# How to use Regex to split a period before non-number?

Tags: python, regex, split

Suppose I have a string

```
line = "Apple is $3.00 higher than banana. Banana is cheap.I hate apple."
```

I know normally `line.split(".")` can split most sentences. However, in this case, I only want to split at the `.` if there is no number after it. Normally, I may do `re.split('\.[^0-9]', line)`, but I don't want to lose my first character after splitting.

Here is the output of `re.split('\.[^0-9]', line)`:

```
['Apple is $3.00 higher than banana', 'Banana is cheap', ' hate apple.']
```

We can see the `I` is dropped.

Comment: could you show your expected result?

Comment: '.(?=[^0-9])' - negative lookahead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform a non-capturing match you can use positive and negative lookaheads. These will peek at the next matched pattern without including that pattern in the result. 
Below is an example of a positive lookahead that will capture all substrings of patA followed by patB.
*Note patA and patB are regex pattern "variables"*

```
patA(?=patB)
```

Below is an example of a negative lookahead that will capture all substrings of patA NOT followed by patB.

```
patA(?!patB)
```

In your case all decimal points not followed by a number should be denoted as

```
\.(?![0-9])
```

Comment: There is one subtle difference between `\.(?![0-9])` and `\.(?=[^0-9])` however. The latter will require something to be after the dot, so it will not match at the end of a string.

Answer (score 2):

Negative lookahead:

```
re.split('\.(?![0-9])', line)
```

Result:

```
['Apple is $3.00 higher than banana', ' Banana is cheap', 'I hate apple', '']
```

Since `I` stands directly after dot, your regular expression `'\.[^0-9]'` will remove `I` because `.I` will match as a separator, and all separators are removed.